# Anyone know a program or a script to turn PHP object/arrays into a nice expandable/collapsable tree?

Tags: php, debugging

I'm working with an open-source CMS that uses some very big multi dimensional arrays/objects. I'm using print_r() to print out these arrays/objects but they are so huge and have so many nested levels it's almost impossible to decipher.

What I need is a way to see this in a collapsed tree where I can expand each branch to drill down.

Is there a script out their to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use firePHP plugin of fireBug.
Check from here http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Use.htm
[image: gosterim]

Comment: +1 for including an image... makes it so much easier when talking about visuals..

Answer (score 2):

Going to answer my own question as I just found this shortly after asking the question:
http://krumo.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jstree.com/demo Please have a look at this...